# how I can connect remotely to a machine and use the console, without knowing its IP address?

Tags: ssh, remote-access

I need to remotely access to the linux console of some machine, but i dont have that IP (and looks like it will be a dinamyc ip)

I have my PC "A", and other PC "B". I have local access to both to install and configure whatever is required, but the PC "B"  will be located elsewhere.

Is ssh the best way to go? how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since Yogipriyo offered a visual solution, here is how you can access SSH without the need of a GUI. Really, it depends on what you are comfortable with; I would personally recommend it.

There are plenty of ways to utilize SSH depending on your OS (that is, "computer A's OS"):

Windows: MobaXTerm, Cygwin, and Putty are the popular ones that I've heard about. I like MobaXTerm simply because you can have multiple tabs.

Mac: Most have the ability to SSH built in via the X11 terminal. You might need to install XQuartz to enable X11 port forwarding though if this isn't working for you.

*Nix: Just get to command line; you probably know that.

Once you are there, Vim is a great editor to know. This again is a "text-based" editor and thus lends itself well to use over SSH.

Keep in mind a lot of this is personal opinion, so explore and find what makes you most productive.

Answer (score 0):

For visual solution, you can use Team Viewer.
It uses it's machine ID (which assigned by the team viewer application once you install it) to connect to the machine. I used it for 2 years at my previous job as remote support and it didn't have any trouble with dynamic IP as long as you have the target's team viewer ID.

For text based, as far as I know you need the target's IP or domain, but alas it still needs static IP.